# Set Textbox background imagebrush in codebehind

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have uploaded my image to my images folder in my Visual Studio solution.

How do I set the background of a textbox to be this image, using VB.net codebehind rather than XAML?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
textbox.Background = New ImageBrush(New BitmapImage(New Uri("ImagePath", UriKind.Relative)))
```

Replace `ImagePath` with the path of image.

Comment: I get 'Type 'BitmapImage is not defined' and a suggestion to import system.windows.media.imaging. Is this right?

Comment: @finisterre yep just import.

Comment: Added an import but now I get **Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New()'** with this **TextBox0a.Background = New ImageBrush(New BitmapImage(New Uri("images/grey-diagonal-stripes.gif", UriKind.Relative)))**